# Typeorm Like query

Tags: node.js, search, typeorm

The like query of typeorm is not working.
Here is the code where I try to search by keyword in email

```
async findAll(findAllQuery: FindAllQuery): Promise<any> {
    const [users, total] = await this.usersRepository.findAndCount(
      {
        where: {
          email: Like(`%${findAllQuery.keyword}%`),
        },
        skip: findAllQuery.page - 1,
        take: findAllQuery.itemsPerPage,
      },
    );
    return { users, total };
  }
```

Any ideas how to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it work avoiding Like, it seems I misunderstood the meaning of Like, all I wanted was to search in users by keyword, so I did something like this, and it worked.

```
async findAll(findAllQuery: FindAllQuery): Promise<any> {
    const options: FindManyOptions<User> = {};

    if(findAllQuery.keyword){
      options.where = {

        $or:[
          {email: RegExp(`^${findAllQuery.keyword}`,'i')},
          {firstName: RegExp(`^${findAllQuery.keyword}`,'i')},
          {lastName: RegExp(`^${findAllQuery.keyword}`,'i')},
          {username: RegExp(`^${findAllQuery.keyword}`,'i')},
        ],
      }
    }

    if(findAllQuery.page){
      options.skip = findAllQuery.page - 1;
    }

    if(findAllQuery.itemsPerPage){
      options.take = findAllQuery.itemsPerPage;
    }

    const [users, total] = await this.usersRepository.findAndCount(options);
    return { users, total };
  }
```